# Is the space $C^1$ a subset of $C^0$?

Tags: general-topology

I learned that $C^0$ in the space of all continuous functions and that $C^1$ is the space of differentiable functions whose derivative is continuous. Was just wondering whether the differentiable functions in $C^1$ are continuous themselves which would imply that $C^1$ is a subset of $C^0$?

Comment: It sure is. Differentiable functions are continuous.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy oh right, what a silly question then haha thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function $f$ is differentiable on its domain, then $f$ is continuous on its domain.

Conclusion: $C^1 \subset C^0.$